# What is the source of Dark Energy?

Tags: cosmology, energy-conservation, space-expansion, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

As the universe expands, wouldn't we need more dark energy pumped into the space to keep the universe expanding. If so, where does the new dark energy come from?

Comment: Obvious answer: the Federal Reserve, which can create something out of nothing, and is the source of the current expansion at least in this nook of the universe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theories with dark energy, an energy density is just a property of space — even “empty” space devoid of matter and radiation. It’s closely related to Einstein’s old idea of a “cosmological constant”. Dark energy isn’t something material that comes from somewhere. As space expands, you simply get more dark energy because there is more volume; a dark energy density is just something all space *has*.

Modern physics concerns itself with mathematical models that explain physical observations. An energy density associated with pure space is just part of today’s cosmological models. It’s there, in a very precise and well-defined way, to explain the observational fact that the expansion of the universe is speeding up rather than slowing down.

From the point of view of the mathematics of General Relativity, it is an extremely simple and natural way to explain this fact. If this seems abstract, it isn’t any more abstract than, say, quantum field theories of particle physics.

As for violating the conservation of energy, that law cannot be consistently formulated for the universe as a whole. We can talk about the *local* conservation of energy, but not the global conservation of energy for the universe.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by local conservation on energgy? And why cannot talk about global conservation? @G.Smith

Comment: By local conservation of energy, I mean that the covariant divergence of the energy-momentum tensor vanishes: $T^{\mu\nu}{}_{;\nu}=0$. We can’t talk about global conservation because the total energy-momentum of the universe can’t be defined in General Relativity, as far as I know.

Answer (score -1):

The question about the origin/increase of (dark) energy is a question of fundamental physics. Let's talk about the elephant in the room: The standard model does not include a fundamental physical understanding for dark energy. Dark energy instead is a place holder term for a type of energy with an assumed negative pressure to give it a repulsive effect. Dark energy has been adopted in the mathematical model of expansion (Friedmann equations) to bring it in line with an apparent acceleration of expansion. This leaves three fundamental possibilities: 1. The standard model is correct, yet we still need a complete theory of energy that includes dark energy. 2. The standard model is just wrong. 3. The standard model is wrong and a complete theory of energy will demonstrate the physics of expansion in a different way than the standard model. I have  [demonstrated recently](https://dualenergyuniverse.org) a physical model for expansion that naturally includes dark energy. It is questionable whether dark energy can  be explained under the standard model without new physics.

Comment: "demonstrated recently"? On the basis of 1 website? The main PDF about negative energy does "explain" it all with any equations (if you ignore the 3 that say no more than x=y).I'm sorry, it will need better evidence than that. And, you should at least mention that YOU are the inventor of the theory.

Comment: hdhondt, appreciated. It’s not a ‘invented’ theory, principle follows directly from applying fundamental physics of energy in gravity. Solves what dark energy is, physics for repulsive effects, increases over time. Happens to resolve physical impossibilities, initial singularity that should never expand, impossibility to define directions for expansion. Hard fundamental evidence for fundamental problem. Does not follow from the familiar (Friedmann) equations, there is a deeper reason for this. Readers may check for themselves, website includes full pre-print, pdfs on evidence/methodology.

Comment: So what (non-familiar) equations does it follow from? Certainly not the 3 silly ones in your PDF. And where's the "hard fundamental evidence"? Statements like "A unique proof for a dual-energy mechanism" or "The fundamental inability of its alternative" do not qualify.

Comment: All addressed, I suggest read at least summaries. ‘Statements’ follow evidence.  Evidence summary https://dualenergyuniverse.org/?page_id=210. Dual-energy mechanism full paper p. 11-13: https://dualenergyuniverse.org/?page_id=151, brief explanation in https://dualenergyuniverse.org/?page_id=291.  Fundamental inability, chart https://dualenergyuniverse.org/?page_id=191. Math for direction in expansion from Newton, not dark energy. Correct, no quantitative math of expansion as kinetic Friedmann model falls away. A testable prediction is made https://dualenergyuniverse.org/?page_id=103.

Comment: hdhondt. Under Newtons law of universal gravitation,  F=Gm1m2/r^2, the attractive gravitational force reverses when one of the two masses considered is negative. Certainly not a silly equation. It directly identifies the driving force for expansion. Standard model instead needs dark energy hypothesis plus an undefined initial acceleration event. The fundamental dual-energy principle for origin of energy ‘think about 0 = -1 +1’ is the intuitive illustration of the principle how energy emerges from 'nothing'. Not more, not less.

Comment: hdhondt, an indication for one of the predictions - that we cannot model early galaxy evolution within the time frame under the standard model - has been published in Science just today. See for yourself, check Federico Lelli et Al, in Science DOI: 10.1126/science.abc1893 or the pointed report on  https://science.ubc.ca/news/portrait-young-galaxy-throws-theory-galaxy-formation-its-head.